# {"Define-se", "Definem-se"} testes relevantes. Qual é o correto?

Tags: regência-verbal

Estou lendo um material técnico e me deparei com a seguinte frase:

> "Define-se testes relevantes para cada história".

Surgiu a dúvida quanto à regência da palavra inicial. Seria `define-se` ou `definem-se`?

Comment: Ambas são possíveis, embora _definem-se_ seja a forma tradicionalmente preferida. Vê a resposta no comentário em cima.

Answer (score -3):

Diria, considerando que é um verbo reflexivo, que o número do tempo verbal deve coincidir com o do substantivo, logo, deveria ser *definem-se*; todavia, admito, que em abstrato, se possa utilizar na terceira pessoa do singular, tal como se conjuga por exemplo o verbo haver, ou seja, *há informações*.

Comment: Não há nada de reflexivo na frase. Os tests não se definem a si mesmos.

Comment: Não me referia a reflexivos mas ao clítico *se* impessoal

Comment: Mas, João, referes `verbos reflexivos`. O @Artefacto critica que «definir» não é reflexivo porque os testes não se definem a eles próprios. Se não discordas, deves editar a resposta para a melhorar. :)